# Why is OpenCV creating weird rectangles?

Tags: python, opencv

I am making a software to track the changes in the areas of different bubbles over the span of a video. I am trying to use the OpenCV multitracker to track these circles, which were created by a Hough's Circle Transformation. My understanding is, I need to define a bounding box to pass to this multitracker tool. So I made the box with basic geometry, but it gave a weird result when I was displaying the box, through the code seen below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vidObj = cv2.VideoCapture('Data/video.mp4')

success = True
tracked = False
multiTracker = cv2.MultiTracker_create()

def Find_Circles(img):
    # Convert to gray-scale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Blur the image to reduce noise
    img_blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 7, 50, 50)
    # Apply hough transform on the image
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 70, param1=110, param2=10, minRadius=20, maxRadius=100)
    
    return circles

def Draw_Circles(img,circles,tracked):
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        
        if tracked is False:
            for i in circles[0, :]:
                
                cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0),2)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (i[0]-i[2], i[1]-i[2]), (i[0]+i[2], i[1]+i[2]), (0, 255, 0),2)
                
        else:
            (success, circles) = multiTracker.update(img)
            print(circles)            
    
while success:
    
    success, img = vidObj.read()
    
    if img is not None:
        Draw_Circles(img, Find_Circles(img),tracked)
        tracked = True
        
        imgplot = plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
        plt.show()

    else:
        success = False
```

Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzbau.png). Any ideas why? Can provide video in mp4 format if needed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to put size limits on detected objects in opencv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causes error:

```
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
```

Values in "circles" can be negative, so you can not use uint16 (unsigned integer) type. Use int16:

```
circles = np.int16(np.around(circles))
```